# Text Tagging based on corpus in PHP

Tags: php, nlp, tagging, text-mining, corpus

I have a corpus or words with tags in xml format. I am creating a web interface to tag user given text based on the corpus I have in Php language. Is there any available code or taggers that do this based on my own corpus which is in xml format?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use the existing Java tagging tools inside your PHP code. Take a look at here: http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/software